# image won't show up in mobile browser

Tags: html, mobile, browser

I have an image in a mobile web page. The image does not appear to show up in the page in a mobile browser. If I access it directly, however, it shows up. If I look at the page in a regular browser, it shows up. We've looked at it with Dolphin for Android, Opera for Android, the native Android browser, and Safari for iPhone. What gives?

the mobile page (contains video)
http://bit.ly/L2YA1i

the problematic image
http://bit.ly/L3QlU3

The HTML for the image (and it's container)

```
<div class="logo"><a href="http://m.celebritycruises.com/m/home.do"><img src="http://media.celebritycruises.com/celebrity/content/en_US/images/cel_misc/logo.jpg" alt="Celebrity Mobile"></a></div>
```

The CSS for the container>

```
.logo {
    padding:10px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<div class="logo">
     <a href="http://m.celebritycruises.com/m/home.do">
        <img src="http://media.celebritycruises.com/celebrity/content/en_US/images/cel_misc/logo.jpg" 
            alt="Celebrity Mobile" border="0" width="259" height="55"
        />
     </a>
</div>
```