# Twitter profile_image url not showing image on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, twitter

I am trying to display twitter user profile image inside my Ionic2 app. I am getting twitter user id on a JSON. the profile URL is like `https://twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal` here `xyz` is user profile id.

The image is displayed in the normal browser view, but profile image is not displayed in mobile browser view (in img tag).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the `width`, `height`, and `border` properties in the HTML `img` tag? It seems someone else had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003118/image-wont-show-up-in-mobile-browser), which was resolved by setting those properties.

Another potential issue is if the size of the images is very large, [certain mobile browsers will reject loading of the image](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/). However, I believe that shouldn't be the case for a Twitter profile image, as those are very small in size. Are you able to post your code at all?

Comment: setting height and width not working. I using simple img tag with hard coded src string too. <img border="0" height="50" width="50" src="https://twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal">. Works fine on dektop but not on mobile

Comment: Anyone can simulate it using normal html page with given img src. Just view it using chrome mobile view

Comment: I'm able to emulate the issue with Chrome as you've stated. I tried loading the [twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal](https://twitter.com/xyz/profile_image?size=normal) link on my mobile phone, and it redirects to the mobile Twitter client, and states that the link does not exist. Perhaps this is an issue on Twitter's end.

Comment: This URL is not supported as part of the Twitter API and does not work in mobile browsers as it redirects to an alternative path to the website. The correct and supported way to get user profile images is via the User object in the Twitter API. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/user-profile-images-and-banners